# Hearing Intervals In A Song

Tags: relative-pitch

Any tips on hearing the intervals that make up the particular sections of a song? I find it easy to identify intervals when I'm listening to them by themselves however when listening to songs in real time I find this a lot more challenging. I have no problem identifying the different sections of a song, I can even identify the instruments, but when listening for the intervals I have to just throw in the towel.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.  Go to jazzbooks.com and download the free ebook "Jazz Handbook", by Jamey Aebersold.

There is a page called Interval Chart.  It shows popular songs where the first two notes are a given interval.  Memorizing on example of each can help to identify unknown intervals.

Example:  Octave:  "Somewhere over the Rainbow"
          Fifth:  "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star"

I've found this technique is very useful for those of us not gifted with perfect pitch.

This book contains a large amount of other useful information, and you can't beat the price! (free)

Answer (score 0):

The intervals are coming fast and thick. It's no wonder you can't identify them. Bit like eating a meal - try one bite at a time. Use the actual words, a syllable/note at a time, and work through that way. If you're trying to get to the point where you can identify a whole line, then what's the point? Listening to a line and being able to play it back on an instrument is a great trick, but I feel you're going to slow yourself down if you translate it all into intervals, then back to the instrument concerned. Just learn scales, and that will do the job. Then you can still do the academic part if necessary.